# Adding a delay into the middle of a function in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

In the spot `//wait 1.5 seconds` what would I say to make it wait 1.5 seconds then complete the code after?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OnclickHeal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    public PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    public Inventory Inventory;

    public Button healButton;

    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = healButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        playerMovement.moveSpeed = 3;
        //wait 1.5 seconds
        playerMovement.moveSpeed = 4;
        playerHealth.currentHealth = 100;
    }
}
```

Also, the line `public Button healButton;` throws an error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Button' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: [When in doubt, be sure to search for your error message on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+type+or+namespace+name+could+not+be+found&mixed=0). In this case, the compiler is complaining that you haven't told it where to find the `Button` type. It's in the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace, so where you have those `using` lines at the top of the file, you should add `using UnityEngine.UI;`. Your IDE should also suggest this fix if you hover over the line giving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Invoke() function to call a function after a certain delay

```
Invoke("DoSomething", 1.5);//this will happen after a delay of 1.5 seconds
```

Where DoSomething is the name of the function that can be defined arbitrarily

```
void DoSomething() {
  //do nothing
  return;
}
```

If you want to read up on more documentation and how you can make better use of them than my naive approach, you can search for *Unity Invoke()* and *Invoke Co-routines*(DoSomething is a co-routine in the above example).

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are for. A coroutine allows you to execute a method with breaks while the rest of the game continues running.

When you have a series of actions which are supposed to be executed with breaks, move them into a method which returns an IEnumerator.

You can now use the construct `yield return WaitForSeconds(1.5f);` in that method to add breaks to this method.

In order for these breaks to work, you have to run it as a coroutine with the method `StartCoroutine(MethodName())`.

```
void TaskOnClick() {
    StartCoroutine(ChangeMoveSpeed());
}

private IEnumerator ChangeMoveSpeed() {
    playerMovement.moveSpeed = 3;
    yield return WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
    playerMovement.moveSpeed = 4;
    playerHealth.currentHealth = 100;
}
```